# ViewPager don't refresh View after second call setAdapter()

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have a problem with ViewPager. When Activity starts I run AsyncTask to download data from server and I call `pager.setAdapter(currentPager)` `currentPager` is empty Fragment with labels for [ViewPageIndicator.TabPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(currentPager);

indicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

when AsyncTask finish download data I call `pager.setAdapter(currentPager);` and first 2 pages is empty, other pages are OK. How to refresh first to pages with appropriate data?
I can't call setContentView without `pager.setAdapter(currentPager);` because i got a NULL pointer

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23263): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.windmobile.rbt.android/com.windmobile.rbt.android.category.CategoryActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPage
r does not have adapter instance.
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager does not have adapter instance.
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator.setViewPager(TabPageIndicator.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at com.windmobile.rbt.android.category.CategoryActivity.onCreate(CategoryActivity.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(23263):        ... 11 more
```

Comment: did you got the answer ? I am facing something similar to your issue.

Comment: have u got the answer mate ?

Answer (score 1):

Dont reset your adapter. Rather then that, update the data source in the adapter when your async task finishes, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: I add currentPager.notifyDataSetChanged(); in AsyncTask in onSuccess(), also I try pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); but it doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: how are you inserting the data into the adapter?

Comment: I make variable for adapter in Activity, first it is empty (not null but it has empty Fragments), I call setContentView, next AsyncTask change this variable and I call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.